# Animate CAShapeLayer as Timer runs

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, cashapelayer

I have a round button with a CAShapeLayer that is on the outside of it. I also have timer that runs as a video plays. As the timer runs, I want to update the CAShapeLayer as if it were a progress indicator. The problem is as the timer runs, the animation on the shapelayer starts jumping around, it isn't smooth. I tried updating it on the mainqueue but that didn't work either.

Where am I going wrong at?

```
lazy var roundButton: UIButton = {
    // create button
}()

var seconds = 15
weak var videoTimer: Timer?
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

func addCAShapeLayerToButton() {

    // there is another shapelayer that is gray used as the outer circle background layer

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: roundButton.center, radius: (roundButton.frame.width / 2) + 10, startAngle: -.pi/2, endAngle: 3 * .pi/2, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = timerCircularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false   
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: nil)
}

func startTimer() {
        
    videoTimer?.invalidate()
    videoTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.timerIsRunning()
    })
    if let videoTimer = videoTimer {
        RunLoop.current.add(videoTimer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func timerIsRunning() {

    if seconds != 0 {
        seconds -= 1

        let recordingProgress: CGFloat = CGFloat(seconds) / CGFloat(15)
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = recordingProgress // tried updating on the mainqueue

        /*
          I also tried
          basicAnimation.fromValue = 0
          basicAnimation.toValue = 1
          basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(recordingProgress)
        */

    } else {

        videoTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

[image]

The red shapeLayer is going to fill the outer gray circle as the timer runs. It's supposed to indicate how much time the user has left to record because there isn't a label that shows the timer as it runs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216811/discussion-on-question-by-lance-samaria-animate-cashapelayer-as-timer-runs).

Answer (score 0):

This sample progress wheel involves a subclass of `UIView` and a subclass of `NSObjet`.  The former creates a wheel view while the latter executes Energizer bunny in animation *until the user stops it*.

**StrokeView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class StrokeView: UIView {
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var strokeColor: UIColor // strokeColor
    var start: CGFloat
    var end: CGFloat
    var radius: CGFloat // radius
    var weight: CGFloat // weight
    var view: UIView // view
    
    init(frame: CGRect, strokeColor: UIColor, start: CGFloat, end: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat, weight: CGFloat, view: UIView){
        self.strokeColor = strokeColor
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.radius = radius
        self.weight = weight
        self.view = view
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.isOpaque = false
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        let bounds = self.bounds
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: radius, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = weight
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

**RotateMe.swift**

```
import UIKit

class RotateMe: NSObject {
    var myView = UIView()
    
    var strokeColor0: UIColor
    var start0: CGFloat
    var end0: CGFloat
    
    var strokeColor1: UIColor
    var start1: CGFloat
    var end1: CGFloat
    
    var strokeColor2: UIColor
    var start2: CGFloat
    var end2: CGFloat
    
    var rect: CGRect
    var radius: CGFloat
    var weight: CGFloat
    var slowness: Double
    var view: UIView
    
    init(rect: CGRect, strokeColor0: UIColor, start0: CGFloat, end0: CGFloat, strokeColor1: UIColor, start1: CGFloat, end1: CGFloat, strokeColor2: UIColor, start2: CGFloat, end2: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat, weight: CGFloat, slowness: Double, view: UIView) {
        self.rect = rect
        self.strokeColor0 = strokeColor0
        self.start0 = start0
        self.end0 = end0
        self.strokeColor1 = strokeColor1
        self.start1 = start1
        self.end1 = end1
        self.strokeColor2 = strokeColor2
        self.start2 = start2
        self.end2 = end2
        self.radius = radius
        self.weight = weight
        self.slowness = slowness
        self.view = view
    }
    
    func circleMe() {
        let minSize = min(rect.width, rect.height)
        let myRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (view.frame.width - minSize)/2.0, y: (view.frame.height - minSize)/2.0), size: CGSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height))
        myView = UIView(frame: myRect)
        let strokeView0 = StrokeView(frame: rect, strokeColor: strokeColor0, start: start0, end: end0, radius: radius, weight: weight, view: view)
        let strokeView1 = StrokeView(frame: rect, strokeColor: strokeColor1, start: start1, end: end1, radius: radius, weight: weight, view: view)
        let strokeView2 = StrokeView(frame: rect, strokeColor: strokeColor2, start: start2, end: end2, radius: radius, weight: weight, view: view)
        myView.addSubview(strokeView0)
        myView.addSubview(strokeView1)
        myView.addSubview(strokeView2)
        //myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        
        let start = 0.0
        let end = start + 2 * Double.pi
        let dur = slowness as Double
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotateAnimation.duration = dur
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = start
        rotateAnimation.toValue = end
        //rotateAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true;
        rotateAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards;
        rotateAnimation.autoreverses = false
        rotateAnimation.isCumulative = true // if set it to no, the view won't rotate and will only move in an awkward way
        myView.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
        view.addSubview(myView)
    }
    
    func stopRotation() {
        myView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

**How to run a progress wheel through a view controller**

[image]

In this case, the user is presented with the start button.  When they tap it, a progress wheel will appear.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Variables
    
    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet var rotateView: RotateMe?
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var endButton: UIButton!
    
    // MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func startTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        startButton.isEnabled = false
        endButton.isEnabled = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            self.makeProgress()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func endTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        startButton.isEnabled = true
        endButton.isEnabled = false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            self.rotateView?.stopRotation()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func makeProgress() {
        let selfFrame = view.frame
        let minFloat = min(selfFrame.size.width, selfFrame.size.height)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: minFloat, height: minFloat)
        let color0 = UIColor.orange
        let start0 = CGFloat(-120.0).degreesToRadians()
        let end0 = CGFloat(0.0).degreesToRadians()
        let color1 = UIColor.purple
        let start1 = CGFloat(0.0).degreesToRadians()
        let end1 = CGFloat(120.0).degreesToRadians()
        
        let color2 = UIColor.green
        let start2 = CGFloat(120.0).degreesToRadians()
        let end2 = CGFloat(-120.0).degreesToRadians()
        
        rotateView = RotateMe(rect: rect, strokeColor0: color0, start0: start0, end0: end0, strokeColor1: color1, start1: start1, end1: end1, strokeColor2: color2, start2: start2, end2: end2, radius: 80.0, weight: 30.0, slowness: 2.0, view: view)
        rotateView?.circleMe()
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    func degreesToRadians() -> CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180.0
    }
    
    func radiansToDegrees() -> CGFloat {
        return self * (180.0 / .pi)
    }
}
```

In your case, run `Timer` and time 15 seconds.  Then simply call

```
rotateView?.stopRotation()
```

Comment: gimme a few to try this out. It's a lot of code to go through.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because it appears it works for a rotating view. The problem in my situation is the client specially wants a record button, the user taps and holds it, and as they hold it the outer gray circle fills with the red color. As I was going through everything in the comments it dawned on me that as their thumb is on the button, they will only be able to partially see the animation as it fills up. If they have a fat thumb they won't be able to see anything. My question is actually a bad idea for the way they want it done. But I have to give them what they want

Comment: All right.  No problem...  This is just basis, and you can customize it in many ways like adding an abort button and on and on.

Comment: Ok cool, I really appreciate the help. You helped me in more ways then one because had we not had these conversations I would've never realized that this whole ux is a terrible idea to begin with. I'm going to let them know this week. Hopefully they abandon it. Thanks for the help enjoy your summer :) Cheers!!!

Comment: All right.  Let me know if you have more questions.  If you want to run the wheel faster, for example, you can change dur in the RotateMe class.

Comment: Ok cool, let speak with the client this week and see what they say. I'm sure they're going to want to make the change. They don't want a label so this I'm going to recommend this progress wheel to them. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I went with your suggestion of just using the animation itself as the timer which worked fine. If you post it as a simple answer (no need to add any code) I'll accept it. Basically the same thing you said in the comments under the question.

Comment: Hi, 2 questions. 1. How can I use this for a horizontal progressBa2. 2. How can I alternate colors for example of certain part of the progress I might need red and the parts orange. The colors will keep changing depending on whatever circumstances up until it's finished